# Non-relative imports - Ionic - Webpack - Sourcemaps are off a few lines on one file in Chrome

Tags: webpack, ionic3

I recently switched my webpack configuration for an Ionic project I am working on to work with non-relative imports. This worked great except I noticed sourcemaps for one of my files was a few lines off.

I modified the [standard ionic-app-scripts 3.1.8 webpack configuration](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/blob/0482bc02b5e4cf8d690fad6dbac9d4e0ed3c3bcf/config/webpack.config.js] using the below config:

```
var path = require("path");
var useDefaultConfig = require("@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js");

module.exports = function() {

  useDefaultConfig.dev.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve("./src"));
  useDefaultConfig.prod.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve("./src"));

  return useDefaultConfig;
};
```

I uploaded the generated sourcemap to source-map-visualization and put it in Pastebin here (the link is really long): https://pastebin.com/xBDX2Vym

I also mentioned it in the Webpack Github Issue [#3165](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3165)